# Are stats being calculated correctly?

Tags: bug

As of this moment, the site has been in beta for 6 days, and contains 70 questions. I'm pretty sure 70/6 is ~ 12, but not according to our stats:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

But seriously, yes, you're right. While caching is involved, this calculation is indeed slightly off. However, it's really mostly noticeable only during early private beta. Not a high priority for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the stats on Area51 don't update in real time. It seems to have updated between the time you visited and I did, however, as they are now reporting 9.4 questions per day. That matches my count: 75 questions with non-negative scores divided by 8 days, yielding 9.375 questions per day.

What is curious, of course, is that the hover text explains *9.4 questions per day on average over the past 8 days*, but the block announces *7 days in beta*. This does seem like a bug of some kind (there are no other new beta sites under two weeks old). But the questions-per-day counter only looks at the past two weeks, so it won't be long before the question is moot.